# MSSQL bulk insert using filenames for tables

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, sqlcmd

I have a list of tables and for each table I have a CSV and a format file. I am trying to comeup with a batch script that would import all the csv with their corresponding format files so far I have this:, the problem is coming on the sql bit, how can i use the variables from the Batch script inside the sql query

> echo off echo off for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (tablelist.txt) do echo %%A
>   sqlcmd -S BNE-MORGANS-SQL -d frontoffice -Q  "bulkinsert.sql" -V
>   'H:\setup\%%A.csv' 'H:\setup\%%A.format'

It says:

```
Sqlcmd: ':\setup\%A.csv' 'H:\setup\%A.format'': Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.
```

if i run it like:

> BULK INSERT mycomp.address FROM 'E:\SQLData\Backup\address.csv' WITH (
>       FIRSTROW = 2,
>       FORMATFILE = 'E:\SQLData\Backup\address.format' ); GO

it works ofcourse but ihave like a 150 csvs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variables in `BULK INSERT` for filenames, however you can use dynamic SQL to process a list of files.

Here's the code I used to import a bunch of PSVs (pipe seperated values), modify as appropriate for your situation. This needs `xp_cmdShell` enabled.

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE #Files (
     Path VARCHAR(200)
    ,FileName VARCHAR(200)
    ,TableName VARCHAR(50)
);

--some variables
DECLARE 
    @Path VARCHAR(200)
   ,@FileName VARCHAR(200)
   ,@TableName VARCHAR(50)
   ,@sql VARCHAR(4000)
   ,@cmd VARCHAR(4000);
```

First run `dir` to grab a list of files to import:

```
--List CSV files to import

SET @Path = 'D:\CSVFiles\'

SET @cmd = 'dir "'+ @path + '*.psv" /b'

INSERT INTO  #Files(FileName) EXEC Master..xp_cmdShell @cmd
UPDATE #Files SET Path = @path WHERE PATH IS NULL

--Remove any null filenames
DELETE FROM #Files WHERE FileName IS NULL
```

Now parse the table name from the file name. This is specific for my solution - change the code to suit yours.

```
UPDATE
    #Files
SET
    TableName = CASE WHEN FileName LIKE 'Authority_Code%'
                     THEN SUBSTRING(FileName, Second.Pos + 1, Last.Pos - Second.Pos - 1)
                     ELSE SUBSTRING(FileName, First.Pos  + 1, Last.Pos - First.Pos  - 1)
                END
FROM
    #Files
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT CHARINDEX('_', FileName) ) AS First ( Pos )
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT CHARINDEX('_', FileName, First.Pos + 1) ) AS Second ( Pos )
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT LEN(FileName) - CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(FileName)) + 1 ) AS Last ( Pos );
```

Now process each file

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT
        Path
        ,FileName
        ,TableName
    FROM
        #Files;
OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Path, @FileName, @TableName;
WHILE @@fetch_status <> -1
    BEGIN

        SET @sql = 'BULK INSERT ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' FROM ''' + @Path + @FileName + ''' ' + 
        ' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'', FIRSTROW = 2, ROWS_PER_BATCH=100000, TABLOCK) ';

        EXEC (@sql);

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Path, @FileName, @TableName;
    END;
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

(Gratutious blog promo - original article here https://www.rednotebluenote.com/2016/04/importing-psma-geocoded-national-address-file-g-naf-to-sql-server/ )